# Adobe mobile sdk - how to disable all adobe calls

Tags: adobe, analytics

I have a ADBMobileConfig json file and my tracking is all working. How do i disable tracking on the entire app ? I'd like a toggle switch somewhere i can use for this i dont want to give a fake server name so the calls fail. I wish there was something in the config file

Comment: I am also stuck up with the same problem. Does anyone know if there is any possibility to disable adobe server calls from mobile app ?

Comment: I ended up just putting in fake server info in the configuration file